# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ there is no package called ‘reprex’

Tags: r, tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘reprex’
```

I am using this version of R **version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)** also I tried to install the library "reprex" but I had this

```
install.packages("reprex")
also installing the dependency ‘withr’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0/withr_2.4.1.tgz'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0/withr_2.4.1.tgz': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0/withr_2.4.1.tgz'
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘withr’ failed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0/reprex_1.0.0.tgz'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0/reprex_1.0.0.tgz': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0/reprex_1.0.0.tgz'
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘reprex’ failed
```

I have macOs Big Sur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the exact same issue on MacOS big sur too. It does work now tho. I installed ggplot2 `install.packages("ggplot2")` which also installed withr, the package that it could not find before.

also installing the dependency ‘withr’

```
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0/withr_2.4.1.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 205896 bytes (201 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 201 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0/ggplot2_3.3.3.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4068756 bytes (3.9 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.9 MB
```

After that, I installed tidyverse again and the problem was solved.

```
> install.packages("tidyverse")
also installing the dependency ‘reprex’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0/reprex_1.0.0.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 478248 bytes (467 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 467 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0/tidyverse_1.3.0.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 433049 bytes (422 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 422 KB

> library(tidyverse)
── Attaching packages ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.3.0 ──
✓ ggplot2 3.3.3     ✓ purrr   0.3.4
✓ tibble  3.0.5     ✓ dplyr   1.0.3
✓ tidyr   1.1.2     ✓ stringr 1.4.0
✓ readr   1.4.0     ✓ forcats 0.5.1
```

I am not sure if the solution was indeed installing ggplot2. This is my first time using R. (I follow a data science course on edX)

Cheers!

- Enzo